# Numerically integrating in to Chebyshev polynomial

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, approximation

I'm trying to find the Chebyshev interpolate for an ODE in a given interval.

That is, given an ODE that looks something like:

$$y'' = g(y) \ y'$$

I want to numerically integrate it inside the window $[0, t)$ and then form an interpolating polynomial for it (in a Chebyshev basis.  An introduction to this idea is in [this chapter](http://www.aip.de/groups/soe/local/numres/bookcpdf/c5-8.pdf) in Numerical Recipes in C).

Forming the Chebyshev polynomial usually involves evaluating the function at Chebyshev points $cos(\Large{\frac{2 \pi i}{2^n}})$, where you actually increase $n$ over several iterations and reuse old evaluations of the function you're approximating.  But I don't think that will work here since $g(y)$ is dependent on $y$.  Presumably I'd have to start the integration fresh when I change $n$.

Are there any tricks I can use here beyond just using something like Runge-Kutta to integrate forward to each of the Chebyshev points?  I'm thinking something like a modified [Bulirsch-Stoer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulirsch%E2%80%93Stoer_algorithm) algorithm where you warp the domain so that the modified midpoint abscissas from Bulirsch-Stoer fall on the Chebyshev points.  Hopefully if the integration is converging after the full step size $H$ it'll converge at all the other Chebyshev points, too?

Comment: Chebyshev pseudo-spectral methods should work fine for a problem like this, if $g$ is smooth enough. Are you familiar with those techniques?

Comment: In the end I just took the dense output polynomial/spline from Dormand-Prince and used it to find the values at the Chebyshev points.